# How to set the previous "MONTH/YEAR" based on the TODAY() value in an SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am working in VS2017 and I am trying to define in my textbox expression the PREVIOUS "MONTH/YEAR" in SSRS.  Today's date is 2021-01-06 and I'm trying in my SSRS expression to configure that and I'm not having any success. Any help/direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code that I've tried in my SSRS expression:

```
="Agent Report " & vbcrlf & "for: " & MonthName(Month(DateAdd("M",-1,Today.Date))) & " - " & 
    IIF(Today.Month = 1, (Year(DateAdd("Y",-1,Today.Date))), (Year(DateAdd("Y",0,Today.Date))))
```

When I execute the code above I'm getting this error in VS2017:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning       [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the
> textrun 'Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error:
> Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type
> 'Date'.       C:\Users\msavoy\source\repos\SSRS Reports_Updated\SSRS
> Reports_Updated\Agents Using a Rater Report.rdl   0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your error comes from, the expression evaluated without an error when I tried it. It did return, what I think, is the wrong answer though.

I simplified it to this...

```
="Agent Report " & vbcrlf & "for: " 
& MonthName(Month(DateAdd("M" ,-1,Today.Date))) 
& " - " 
& IIF(Today.Month = 1, Today.Year - 1, Today.Year)
```

This returned

```
Agent Report 
for: December 2020
```

Comment: Alan, thank you so much.  I got caught in the weeds.  You just made it a lot easier.  Appreciate your time and help.